# How to interpret "schon" here?

Tags: meaning

> Du hast das wirklich erledigt! Ich hatte **schon** Angst, es wäre vielleicht noch früh für dich.

I'm torn between two possible meanings:

1. really / to tell you the truth / as a matter of fact / wirklich
2. just serving as a filler word

Answer (score 4):

Neither. **Schon** means **already** here.

> Ich hatte Angst, es wäre vielleicht noch früh für dich.
>
> Ich hatte **schon** Angst, es wäre vielleicht noch früh für dich.
>
> Ich hatte **bereits** Angst, es wäre vielleicht noch früh für dich.

The sentences with **schon/bereits** focus on the fact the *Angst* built up until the moment of the talk.